# How to disable image loading in capybara-webkit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

Poltergeist driver has the feature where you can turn image loading off, how can I achieve the same with capybara-webkit?

This would make my app faster since we load some images using vanity urls.

Answer (score 5):

I was debugging some request tests and I switched back and forth from capybara-webkit to poltergeist to selenium. There is a nice feature poltergeist has which is disable image loading and I discover this awesome dude made it possible for capybara-webkit.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/commit/646eabc68d5c6fe5bc0515492ee9ba04c5f49b8f

The problem is that is not well documented. Here is how you turn image loading off in capybara-webkit.

```
# spec_helper.rb
Capybara.register_driver :webkit do |app|
  driver = Capybara::Webkit::Driver.new(app)
  driver.browser.set_skip_image_loading true
  driver
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alan's answer didn't work for me but pointed me to this:

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :type => :feature) do
    page.driver.browser.set_skip_image_loading true
  end
end
```

UPDATE: Actually, both settings seem to have no effect, or not always. Scratching my head...

Answer (score 0):

[Capybara docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#configuration) suggest you want:

```ruby
Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.skip_image_loading
end
```